# Swift: Force Unwrapped returns nil without crashing

Tags: swift, swift2, forced-unwrapping

Below is the code I have in playground:

```
let aNumber : NSNumber? = nil

func testFuction() -> NSNumber!{
    return aNumber
}

dump(testFuction())
```

Output:

```
- nil
```

I am confused as to why it's not crashing.  The return value `NSNumber!` is obviously nil, but it's being force unwrapped.  Shouldn't this be crashing?  Please explain.

Comment: Use `print` instead of `dump` and it crashes as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning an implicitly unwrapped optional, `NSNumber!`. The underlying data type returned is an optional, but it will automatically be unwrapped every time you use it. Swift includes this type so that you don't have to use exclamation points after variables that you know will be non-nil after a certain point (for instance, an instance variable that starts off as nil but is initialized before it is ever used). Implicitly unwrapped optionals are allowed to contain nil values, but you will trigger a runtime error if the variable is nil when you actually try to use it because it is force-unwrapped at the point of use.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "it will automatically be unwrapped every time you use it".  I was under the impression that `func testFuction() -> NSNumber!` is forcefully unwrapping it before returning the value?

Comment: @user1107173, to forcefully unwrap a value, you need to put the exclamation mark after the value, not after the function's return type.

Comment: So, is there a even a point in function returning a value with a bang in function signature?

Comment: "it will automatically be unwrapped every time you use it" -- say you have `var x: Int? = 5` and `var y: Int! = 5`. Then `print(x)` prints `Optional(5)` while `print(y)` prints `5`. So `x` is not unwrapped, and is a normal optional, while `y` is unwrapped before being printed, so just `5` is printed. `y` is always assumed to be non-nil, and so is unwrapped without the explicit use of an exclamation point. `func testFuction() -> NSNumber!` returns an implicitly unwrapped NSNumber optional, but nothing happens to the returned value until you use it (like `y` in the previous example).

Comment: In fact, in practical usage it makes almost no sense to return an implicitly unwrapped optional; either return a true optional, or return a non-optional and force unwrap the return value within the function body. Returning an implicitly unwrapped optional may make debugging harder, as you do not find out that you've wrapped nil in an implicitly unwrapped optional until you attempt to use the return value.

Answer (score 2):

`nil` implicitly-unwrapping optionals crash when they unwrap, and passing an optional to `dump` doesn't unwrap it. Implicit unwrapping happens when you pass an (implicitly wrapped) optional value (T!) as value of the unwrapped type (T), but if the function accepts an optional, no unwrapping occurs.

You can do implicit unwrapping by doing something like `let unwrapped: NSNumber = testFunction()`, and this will crash.

If you meant to forcefully unwrap the value, the exclamation mark goes after the value, not after the return type:

```
func testFuction() -> NSNumber {
    return aNumber!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns an implicitly unwrapped optional. It will be implicitly unwrapped if you try to use it as `NSNumber`, but it is still an optional, and hence it can legitimately have `nil` value.

If you put an exclamation point after `aNumber` and remove it from the function return type, you would get a crash as you expect:

```
func testFuction() -> NSNumber {
    return aNumber!
}
```